# Dividing that high of n-element heap is [log2(n)] + 1

Tags: algorithm

Can you please help me to divide that n-element heap is  [log2(n)] + 1?

I have searched everywhere and try to understood but with no effects.

Comment: How do you mean? Do you mean splitting a heap is log2n+1? Or something else?

Comment: I mean that i must divide that any n-element heap has ⌊Log[2,n]⌋+1 high. 
I hope that I correctly explain that.

Comment: Oh, determine if a heap has a height of log2(n)+1?

Comment: I must divide that. This is thesis and I must divde. This is my exercise from Algorithm Subject.